# Updating Model Instance with Django

Tags: python, django, class, view

I am initiating an instance of Estate with CreateView1. It works fine, even though it is a template view!! Now I want to be redirected to UpdateView2 and update those fields (I have a good reason for that). How can I pass the pk of instance 1 to the second view, and how to edit those fields? Any help would be much appreciated!!

views.py

```
class CreateView1 (TemplateView):
    template_name = 'estate_form1.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form = RegisterForm()
        args = {'form': form,}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            estate = form.save(commit=False)
            estate.save()
            form = RegisterForm()
            return redirect('register:update2')
        args = {'form': form,}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

class UpdateView2(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'estate_form2.html'
    model = Estate
    fields = ["price", "area"]
```

estate_form1.html and estate_form2.html

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.IntegerField(label="Price:")
    area = forms.IntegerField(label="Area:")

    Class Meta:
       model = Estate
       fields = ('price', 'area')
```

Thanks already for the support!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: It looks like 2.0 from your redirect code.

Comment: Can you post your urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to your redirect function in CreateView1 as an argument.

```
    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            estate = form.save(commit=False)
            estate.save()
            form = RegisterForm()
            return redirect('register:update2', pk=estate.id)
```

Then make sure that your url.py file is setup to receive the id. It'll look something like:

```
    path('register/<int:pk>/', UpdateView2.as_view(), name='update2'),
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but as an additional note, I'd consider using a CreateView instead of TemplateView. That would allow you to use success_url to redirect.